# Angular SEO / NodeJS / PhantomJS - Serve static html files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nginx, phantomjs

I am implementing my own PhantomJS solution in order to provide snapshots to Search Engine crawlers.

- My snapshots are here: /public/snapshots
- My URL are like this: http://example.com/#!/a/b/c

When a crawler comes, the url's /#!/ gets transformed like this: http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/a/b/c

I want to serve static files from /public/snapshots to the crawler when it crawls one of my page.

### Current solution

I catch the change of URLs and rewrite this:

- http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment=/a/b/c (with nginx)
- into this: http://example.com/snapshots/a/b/c

It comes to a route on my NodeJS, where I get the html file name according to the url parameters. In this case it would be **/snapshots/a/b/c.html**

I get the file with:

```
fs.readFile(file_path, function(err, content)
{
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(content);
});
```

### Problem

When I set the Content-Type as HTML, Angular / Express makes a redirection and my url gets like this:

- http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/a/b/c#!/

If I go to this url I can see the correct /a/b/c.html snapshot file but after a few milliseconds, I get redirected to my homepage.

### Questions

- How can I serve static files without having Express nor Angular redirecting it?
- If I make a redirection from http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/a/b/c to http://example.com/snapshots/a/b/c.html -which works well-, will the search engines agree with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you solved it and if so can you give me some code example on how to implement this ? I'm new to nodejs and phantomjs so if it could be possible to share the whole project via github or something?

Comment: As a solution, I decided to use Prerender.io, which is doing this part of the job for me. It is easy to implement, reliable, and the dashboard they provide is ok. I recommend this tool to you if you don't have that much time to develop your own serve-a-snapshot-feature.